# Two-color animation for an inset box shadow around the screen - CSS

Tags: css, animation, gradient, mask

I'm attempting to create an animation for an inset box shadow around the screen with two colors smoothly transitioning. My current approach involves using a mask to hide half of the screen and making it rotate, but the animation isn't as smooth as desired, and some corners lack shadows.
CODE:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
    0%, 100% {
        -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, black) content-box;
    }

    25% {
        -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, black) content-box;
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to left, transparent, black) content-box;
    }

    75% {
        -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, black) content-box;
    }
}

.glow,
.glow2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 1;
}

.glow {
    -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to right, transparent, black) content-box;
    -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
    mask-composite: exclude;
    animation: rotateAnimation 5s ease-in-out infinite;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0, 0, 255);
}

.glow2 {
    -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent) content-box;
    -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
    mask-composite: exclude;
    animation: rotateAnimation 5s ease-in-out infinite reverse;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="glow"></div><div class="glow2"></div>
```

I have tried using a mask to hide half of the screen and applying an inset box shadow with two colors, but the transition isn't very smooth, and there are issues in the corners. I expected to achieve a seamless and continuous animation with two colors in the box shadow.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand you’re trying to create a smooth transition between two colors for an inset box shadow animation. The issue you’re facing might be due to the abrupt change in gradients at each 25% interval of the animation.

One possible solution could be to use a `pseudo-element` with a background gradient and animate the `background-position` instead. This way, you can achieve a smoother transition between the colors. Here’s an example that could useful for your code:

```
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.glow {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.glow:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(0, 0, 255), rgba(255, 0, 0));
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 5s ease infinite;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}   
</style>

<div class="glow"></div><div class="glow2"></div>
```